# React native date time picker selection

Tags: react-native, datetimepicker

I'd like some help.
I used the package @react-native-community/datetimepicker this way :

```html
<View>
    <DatePicker
     date={this.state.datetimeS}
     mode="datetime"
     format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"
     confirmBtnText="Confirm"
     cancelBtnText="Cancel"
     hideText={true}
     showIcon={true}
     onChange={(datetime) => {
     this.setDateTimeS(datetime);
      }}
     />
   <Text style={styles.textsmall}>Select a date
 </Text>
</View>
```

[image]

IThat's cool but when I choose the date, I want it to replace the text "select a date" (only when the date is picked)

Can you help me to do that ? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe ask conditionally? Try something like this:

```
<View>
    <DatePicker
     date={this.state.datetimeS}
     mode="datetime"
     format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"
     confirmBtnText="Confirm"
     cancelBtnText="Cancel"
     hideText={true}
     showIcon={true}
     onChange={(datetime) => {
     this.setDateTimeS(datetime);
      }}
     />

  {this.state.datetimeS == null ? <Text style={styles.textsmall}>Select a date
 </Text> : <Text> {this.state.datetimeS} </Text> } 

</View>
```

This will check if your date state is already filled with a date value. For this to work the default value for datetimeS has to be null. If it is Null so no date is picked it shows the text, if a date is picked it should display the date.

If your default state for datetimeS is for example like this:

```
 state={ datetimeS: ""}
```

then you can check it like this:

```
    {this.state.datetimeS.trim() == "" ? <Text style={styles.textsmall}>Select a date
 </Text> : <Text> {this.state.datetimeS} </Text> }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the state to change it. Use dateTimeS in state and update it at onChange function?

`<Text style={styles.textsmall}>{this.state.dateTimeS === undefined ? 'Select a date' : 'other text'}</Text>`